# How to check out code from local git directory

Tags: git

I downloaded a source code package. It is nearly 3GB. But it is a empty directory and just contains a **.git** directory. How can I check out code from it?

Comment: Depends on what's in that `.git` dir, with any luck at all everything's good to go and `git checkout` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
git clone ./directoryofRepo ./WorkingDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard
```

If the directory is actually repo.git, then

```
git clone repo.git repo
```